# Why does Celery revoke tasks immediately?

Tags: python, celery

When I queue up a task, **Celery receives the task and then immediately (in the same millisecond) revokes it**- why?

```
[2020-11-03 13:15:39,966: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: hidden_task_name[758d74d2-1226-4523-ad9a-ee732aecf3c8]   expires:[2020-11-03 13:20:30+00:00]
[2020-11-03 13:15:39,966: INFO/MainProcess] Discarding revoked task: hidden_task_name[758d74d2-1226-4523-ad9a-ee732aecf3c8]
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out **the tasks' expiration dates were in the past**.  I thought I was scheduling the task's expiration date for 5 minutes in the future, but I was setting the **expiration date in UTC**, while my server (and Celery) are using my **local timezone**, (which is behind UTC).